Make change value in cell after selecting from dropdown list work when drag to value other cells
I have a dropdown list where I can select the full name of a person and when I select a name, it should show the abbreviation in the cell.
I got this working somehow, but my problem now that I want to be able to drag to fill to other cells.
With tweaking my code a little but I got it to work but I still get an error message.
ERROR 13: Type Mismatch

This is the code I'm using:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    selectedVal = Target.Value
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedVal, Worksheets("Bestuurders").Range("Omschrijving"), 2, False)

        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If

End Sub 

What can I do to make sure I don't get this error message?

Please clarify the detail drag to value to other cells. eg. drag cell A1 to B2 ? I can't reproduce the error on M365.

Assuming you mean "drag to fill": when Target is not a single cell then Target.Value is an array.  You need to process each cell in Target individually.  Ideally you set Application.EnableEvents = False before updating the worksheet from your VBA, so you don't re-trigger the event.

Yes, I mean drag to fill. When I select cell D2 and I want to drag and fill with same value to F2, then I get this error message.

This effect can also be achieved without VBA, but it is a bit of a hassle.
In the selected range of cells (e.g. G7:G10) we enter a list of abbreviations, in this case A, B, C, D. Each cell from this range is formatted in a custom way using the code (for G7):
;;;"Person A"
In other cells, analogically, we change only "Person A" to "Person B", etc.
In another range of cells (e.g. H7:H10), we create references to cells from the previous range. Each reference must be entered separately into a previously unformatted cell, e.g. in H7 we enter =G7 etc. Do not copy these references, otherwise the custom formatting will transfer incorrectly. If there are a lot of cells, you can do it with a macro.
Now in one cell of the working range (B2:E5), we define a drop-down list specifying the range of cells H7:H10 as the source. This cell can be dragged and copied at will. Cells in the working range are in the General format.
You can also place the cells with the data for the list on another worksheet, or you can use the name of the range.


I found a working solution. this is the code I used.
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' Voorkom meerdere celwijzigingen tegelijk
    
    Dim selectedVal As String
    selectedVal = Target.Value
    
    If selectedVal = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim wsBestuurders As Worksheet
    Set wsBestuurders = Worksheets("Bestuurders")
    
    Dim selectedNum As Variant
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedVal, wsBestuurders.Range("Omschrijving"), 2, False)
    
    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Schakel gebeurtenissen tijdelijk uit om een oneindige lus te voorkomen
        Target.Value = selectedNum
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Schakel gebeurtenissen weer in
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Voorkom dat de code wordt uitgevoerd bij dubbelklikken
    Cancel = True
End Sub


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
